On Click in subform to add another row of data entry fields to enter new record
This is all data entry of new records. I have a form frmLoad, enter the truck, driver, miles the load was, date, etc.
SubForm - subfrmStops each load has from 1-? stops, that subfrm needs the StopNum, Pounds, Customer.
SubSubForm - subfrmFees - Because each stop can have 1-? Fees added on that need a description, amount, etc.
3 Separate tables each with unique ID's, tbl Load has LoadID, StopDetailID (autonum) with LoadID FK, FeeDetails tbl has an autonum PK and LoadID and StopID FK's.
That all seems to be fine, queries all work so relationships and structure is as solid as it can be for such a complex invoicing requirement.
PROBLEM
Data Entry of the Load. Main form for the load details is good, subsubformFeeDetails is opened in datasheet view from a button on subformStops with all the passed in values hidden, they just select the FeeType from a cmboBox and enter the amount however many rows(records) then when they close it they're back at the main form.
The middle has me stuck! Datasheet does not seem like a good idea, visually, and for adding all the fees.

How can I design this so the user can still see all the stops as the amounts from each one get summed together to create the totals for the Load record.
Attempted VBA to insert another row of all the text boxes and a new add fees button to enter the new record but the first row of controls are all bound so that was a fail.
Possibly all unbound controls, VBA can insert the new rows of controls every time they click add new, have the VBA set to use some sort of increment on the names of each control like txtPounds1, txtPounds2, etc. Then when they are done and click save VBA to read each of those "1's" into one new record, "2's" into another new record, etc. But then the Add Fees button would have to know what StopNumber and other fields to put into the datasheet on open so they are entering FeeDetails for the correct stop.
Also, that sounds like an INSANE amount of work to write all that....There has to be a simpler way!

This seems like a design issue, but SO is for helping with coding issues, thus your question is OT here. Try a forum like UtterAccess.

You aren't creating a record in a related child table for each fee item? If you aren't and you just want to save an aggregated total, then of course there will be an insane amount of coding to accomplish.

"simpler way" would be data entry to a dependent table and aggregate with query or report design.

Are your totals for the load stored in the load table, or are they simply calculated in query or in the fields themselves?

I have total miles stored in, it's endodometer - current in the tblTrucks so I have to store that. Each fee it's amount stored. LoadID relates them all, StopID has pounds per stop stored.
It is a bizarre structure, I don't like it but I don't see another way. Customer # comes in at stop. There's an IsInvoiced flag on each table. Put in Loads, bulk run invoices. Invoicing queries If flag = false to get the calcs. Print by Cust# first.  Set flag on each stopID it takes, the query if all stops are done per LoadID, if so, set flag.  Haven't started that part yet, we'll see!

Query can pull value from another record to calculate difference in odometer readings. Involves a correlated subquery. See http://allenbrowne.com/subquery-01.html#AnotherRecord

True, good article. But all those trips to the truck wash n WalMart betweren Loads add up. Mileage gets read a LOT. When does rate/mile goes up, service due, warranty exps, Driver record queries, Idk,.  In load entry it's a hyperlink to a little pop up with just that field to edit. So it's as accurate as possible in the table.   I'm up to 4.0 on this, thought I had it wrapped. Didn't account for more than one customer per stop. Smh. I detest concatenated ID fields but I'm not seeing another way. And I some point I just want to be DONE! Lol
